# Obtener valor de celda1, celda2 y celda4

Tags: php

Quiero obtener `Columna1`, `Columna2`, `Columna4` pero he intentado con `mysqli_fetch_array` pero creo que no es la función correcta he mirado pero no sé que función estoy necesitando para extraerlo.

```
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $fila['Nombre'][1];
```

Ya que así me sale la primera letra pero no me sale `Nombre[1]`, `Nombre[2]` si me pueden echar un cable

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida. Por favor, da más detalles sobre lo que quieres. Si el nombre, apellido, etc. O si lo que quieres es hacer un split del nombre para obtener caracteres de él. La pregunta no se entiende muy bien.

Comment: Lo que quiero es obtener solo los nombre específicos es decir $fila['Nombre'][0] seria Mario $fila['Nombre'][2] seria Vicente $fila['Nombre'][4] seria Juan

Comment: Pues es como te dice @MarioGuiber en su respuesta. Tienes que abrir un bucle e ir leyendo fila por fila. En el ejemplo que él te puso se supone que en la tabla hay una columna llamada `Nombre` y que la misma está en el  `SELECT`. Si no se llama nombre le pones el nombre de la columna, tal y como indica Mario en su respuesta. O si el nombre es la 1ª columna del `SELECT`  lo pones así: `echo $fila[0];`. Yo usaría `fetch_assoc` y los nombres de columna, así se entiende más lo que uno está haciendo, sobre todo cuando el programa crezca.

Comment: El problema con el bucle es que me muestra múltiples valores de nombres y solo necesito 3 nombres en cuestión a los que pueda llamar directamente para hacer uso.

Comment: Bueno pero ese es un problema de tu consulta entonces, debes escribirla de modo que te traiga solamente esos nombres que quieres, poniéndole un `WHERE` por ejemplo donde indiques el criterio por el que filtrarías esos nombres. No es una buena práctica traer un montón de datos de la base de datos para luego usar sólo tres, debes filtrar para que te traiga solamente esos tres. Es un principio que debes aplicar siempre: *solicita solamente aquello que vayas a usar*. ¿Acaso si vas a un restaurante pides 50 platos? No te los comerás todos y no quiero estar cerca cuando te traigan la factura :-)

Comment: Si el problema no es filtrar es obtenerlos ya que por la consulta puedo filtrarlos pero seguiria obteniendo 3 en conjunto y los necesito para llamarlos directamente ejemplo echo "<h2>" . $row['Nombre'] . "</h2>"; echo "<h2>" . $row['Nombre'] . "</h2>"; (segundo nombre)

Comment: Propongo que [edites la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/210625/edit) y te expliques mejor, porque no te entiendo. ¿Acaso estás trayendo una sola fila con los tres nombres?  ¿Cómo vienen los datos realmente? Si vienen en filas distintas, con la respuesta de Mario podrás mostrar los nombres que vienen en la consulta. Si vienen en una sola fila con un separador, entonces debes usar `explode`. Lo que dices es contradictorio, pues en un comentario dices que te trae todos los nombres y ahora dices que te los trae filtrados. Entonces ya no se sabe como vienen los datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano te explico si uso $fila['Nombre']  me trae el primer nombre la tabla se compone de ID, Nombre y otros campos. En ese caso me trae el nombre del primer id y quiero que me traiga ese nombre y dos nombres más por separado. Se que había una forma usando [1] y [2] pero no la localizo ahora mismo.

Comment: A ver cuando haces una consulta, los resultados vienen como en un puntero, debes empezar a recorrerlos para ir obteniendo cada fila de esos resultados, por eso se suele usar un `while` como indica @MarioGuiber en su respuesta. En cada paso de ese `while` se va leyendo cada fila de esa consulta. ¿Entiendes eso o no? Si dices que los datos vienen filtrados en la consulta, deberían venir **tres filas**, y se imprimirán los tres nombres que vienen en la consulta uno debajo del otro. ¿No es eso lo que quieres? ¿No funciona así el código que te indica Mario? ¿Cómo funciona entonces, qué imprime?

Comment: La llamada es sin filtrar ya que la estoy usando general para extraer información y si hago lo que comenta mario me imprime todos los nombres hasta ahí correcto pero yo solo quiero tres nombres fila 0 fila 2 y fila 4 y creo que había opción para eso.

Comment: Le puedes poner un contador al `while` y detenerlo en la fila que quieras. De todos modos me parece mal que traigas todos los datos si no los necesitas.

Comment: Si los datos los traigo porque los estoy utilizando pero al mismo tiempo queria extraer datos específicos sin tener que generar una consulta para es detalle.

Comment: Entiendo. En ese caso sí se justifica. Si sólo quieres los primeros cuatro, puedes hacer esto: `$i=0;
    do {
        echo $fila["Nombre"].PHP_EOL;
        $i++;
    } while( $i < 4 && $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result));` Sabiendo que la columna se llama `Nombre` y está en el `SELECT`.

Comment: Si pero no me sirve esa opción crees que sea necesario hacer una llamada directa llamando al valor en cuestión y como podría almacenarlo optimamente.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta que he publicado. Si vas a hacer uso del conjunto de resultados en varia partes, conviene que lo guardes en un array y que luego trabajes sobre ese array.

Comment: Sería para sacarlo de forma individual y no lo logro

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con sacarlo de forma individual? En el código al final de mi respuesta puedes hacer algo así: `$nombre1=$arrDatos[0]["Nombre"];` directamente, **sin usar bucles**.

Comment: Cómo sería de ese modo no lo ubico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con este código podrás imprimir el nombre de los cuatro primeros registros del conjunto de resultados:

```
    $i=0; 
    do{
        echo $fila["Nombre"]."<br>"; 
        $i++; 
      } while($i < 5 && $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
```

Consiste en leerlos dentro de un bucle `do... while` el cual terminará cuando el contador sea menor a `5`, o sea, cuando llegue al registro `4`.

Nótese que he usado `mysqli_fetch_assoc` porque `fetch_array` produce dos valores (uno asociativo y otro numérico) por cada columna, lo cual no parece conveniente desde el punto de vista de la optimización.

### Atención a esto

Ten en cuenta que el `while` va a iterar sobre tu conjunto de resultados y si lo detienes en el registro número 4, si por algún motivo intentas volver a recuperar datos, el puntero de los resultados se encontrará donde lo detuviste.

Si pones dos veces seguido el código del `do ... while`  de más arriba verás que en la segunda parte te imprimirá de nuevo cuatro registros, pero empezando por el último, donde se quedó el puntero.

Si quieres usar tus datos en varios escenarios, puedes entonces recuperarlos todos en un array y luego usar ese array para leerlos en esas diferentes partes.

Por ejemplo:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         $arrDatos[]=$row;
    }
    /*Puedes cerrar el conjunto de resultados*/
    $result->close();
```

Hay tienes en `$arrDatos` todos los resultados, no dependientes del puntero del conjunto de resultados, el cual puedes cerrar y usar `$arrDatos` en lo adelante.

Por ejemplo, para leer los primeros cuatro puedes hacerlo así:

```
    $i=0; 
    do{
        echo "-".$arrDatos[$i]["Nombre"].PHP_EOL; 
        $i++; 
      } while($i < 5 && $arrDatos);
```

O con un bucle `foreach`:

```
    $i=0;
    foreach ($arrDatos as $row){
        $i++;
        echo $row["Nombre"].PHP_EOL;
        if ($i==4){ break;}
    }
```

Y si se ofrece leer todos los datos:

```
    foreach ($arrDatos as $row){
        echo $row["Nombre"].PHP_EOL;            
    }
```

---

#### EDICIÓN

Si quieres crear variables usando filas específicas, puedes acceder a cada fila por el índice de `$arrDatos` y luego por la clave, `Nombre`  en este caso.

Por ejemplo:

```
$nameOne   = $arrDatos[0]["Nombre"]; //Posición 0 o fila 1
$nameTwo   = $arrDatos[1]["Nombre"]; //Posición 1 o fila 2 
$nameThree = $arrDatos[2]["Nombre"]; //Posición 2 o fila 3
```

Etc.

Ahí se crearon tres variables con los nombres de las tres primeras personas en el array. Estamos siempre dando por supuesto que esa columna se llama `Nombre` en tu base de datos. Si no, debes poner el nombre que tenga para que funcione.

Comment: @Vicente revisa la **EDICIÓN** al final de la respuesta.

Comment: Con $nameOne   = $arrDatos[0]["Nombre"]; me lo devuelve vació.

Comment: @Vicente ¿qué muestra un `var_dump($arrDatod);`?

Comment: Me lo devuelve NULL el valor del array.

Comment: Escribí mal el nombre en mi comentario, debe ser `var_dump($arrDatos);` Si no te funciona muestra cómo has escrito todo el código, lo puedes poner al final de tu pregunta, editándola.

Comment: Así lo tengo,

 $Nombre = "SELECT * FROM servicio";
 $result = $conn-> query($Nombre);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 
    // Código extra       
    
    $i=0; 
    do{
        echo $fila["Nombre"]."<br>"; 
        $i++; 
      } while($i < 5 && $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
      
      $nameOne   = $arrDatos[0]["Nombre"];
      var_dump($arrDatos);

Comment: No estás llenando el array de datos como explico en la respuesta: **`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ $arrDatos[]=$rwo; } /*Puedes cerrar el conjunto de resultados*/ $result->close();`**

Comment: Me sigue dando un array  null

Comment: ¿Seguro que esa consulta trae datos? Pon un `var_dump($row);` dentro del `while`. Yo hice pruebas y me funciona. ¿Tienes una columna llamada `Nombre` y la misma es parte del `SELECT`?

Comment: Disculpa había otro error en esta línea: `$arrDatos[]=$rwo`, debe estar escrito así: **`$arrDatos[]=$row;`**

Comment: Ahora si algo así buscaba pero en orden aquí sale desordenado me suena que anteriormente hice algo similar pero en orden.

Comment: El orden quizá lo mejor sea establecerlo en la consulta poniendo por ejemplo al final `ORDER BY Nombre`

Comment: Era error mio que había dejado código anterior el error es que obtiene $arrDatos[0]["Nombre"] el segundo nombre y puede cntinuar con el tercero y cuarto... pero el primero se lo salta si mal no recuerdo se podia poner en negativo pero no me lo muestra el primero.

Comment: Vale acabo de ver que es que anteriormente estaba usando $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); al estar metido ya en el tuyo no es necesario. Respecto a cerrar el conjunto en que difiere,

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que quieres decir... Una cosa, quita todos los `while` que puedas tener, dejando solamente el que llena `$arrDatos` , por lo mismo que ya expliqué en la respuesta. Si mueves el puntero y vuelves a intentar leer los datos te mostrará a partir de donde se quedó el puntero la última vez. Debes quitar también cualquier llamada a `fetch_assoc` o `fetch_array` que puedas tener, dejando solamente la que interesa. O sea, una única llamada a ese método.

Comment: En cuanto a cerrar, es para liberar recursos. Dado que ya tienes todos los datos en el array, no necesitas más el conjunto de resultados, lo puedes cerrar para liberar posibles recursos que pueda estar usando.

Comment: Si eso hice por eso solvente el problema con tu linea más que sobra  ya que algo así buscaba en vez de realizar peticiones exactas es más limpio y sabía que se podía no sabes como te lo agradezco!!

Comment: Me alegro. Puedes darla por solucionada activando la flecha de cotejo a la izquierda. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitar para mostrar tus columnas es recorrerlo mediante un bucle. Cuando lanzas una query con `mysqli_query($link,$sql);` y sabes que vas a obtener varias filas, tal y como lo tienes en tu código, solo te mostrara tu primera fila. Prueba hacer con un bucle así:

```
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $fila['Nombre'].'<br>';
}
```

La variable `$fila['Nombre']` dentro de ese bucle, te mostrara todos tus datos del campo **Nombre**. Si quieres mostrar otro campo de tu base de datos bastaría con poner por ejemplo `$fila['Apellidos']`.

Espero que se haya entendido correctamente y te pueda servir.

Un saludo.

Comment: Si hasta ahí llegue pero no quiero todos los campos de nombre si no el campo1, campo2, campo3  que pueda usar por separado.

Comment: Puedes explicármelo un poco mejor? No logro entender lo que intentas conseguir.

Comment: Lo que quiero es obtener solo los nombre específicos es decir $fila['Nombre'][0] seria Mario $fila['Nombre'][2] seria Vicente $fila['Nombre'][4] seria Juan